# How to move text right in Text Input

Tags: react-native, styling, react-native-textinput

I wanted to style up my app by adding *border radius* to a text input, I observed that the text in the input is going outside from the *corners* how can I move it to the right.

This is the Text Input code

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Username"
    placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
    maxLength={35}
    style={styles.input}
/>
```

This is the Style code

```
input: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    height: 50,
    width: 320,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginTop: 35,

    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'oswald',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a padding to the input and that will give you the space you need.

```
input: {
    paddingHorizontal: 5px,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    height: 50,
    width: 320,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginTop: 35,

    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'oswald',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
  }
```

You can also just have padding instead of `paddingHorizontal`, but that will increase the height of your input

Comment: My pleasure! If this helped you please accept the answer.